# Place text in center of button programmatically in a TableLayout

Tags: java, android

Here is my code snippet. How can I center the text present inside the button? please help?

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                     (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       tableRowParams.setMargins(10, 20, 10,2);
        tableRowParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(120, 100));
        b.setId(100 + i);
        b.setPadding(1, 10, 50, 10);
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0080ff"));
        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        b.setText("log");
        b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        b.setAllCaps(false);

        row.addView(b);
```

Image: [image]

Comment: **???!** Buttons already place their text in the center position. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: It's aligned in left corner. Added picture.

Comment: It looks like `b` is a **TextView**, not a **Button**.

Comment: b is a button not Text view

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson It is not duplicate because he had tried the answers  suggested in the duplicate question you refer to, and still the problem persists. His problem is elsewhere, on the padding, as I wrote in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the left and right padding for the button and it should work.

Remove this line or make left and right equal

```
b.setPadding(1, 10, 50, 10);
```

Comment: Yup. That Worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the gravity field as you would in XML

```
button.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

Comment: I am generating buttons dynamically

Comment: and that doesnt work?

Comment: Not able to align the text to center

Comment: why are you adding the table layout to the button again?